# MTP Host has stopped

Tags: android

Alguien sabe por que al eliminar mi aplicacion me sale este aviso

[image: situacion]

Comment: cuando la eliminas, ¿tienes el usb conectado al pc?

Comment: nooo, virtualizo el dispositivo con GeymMotion

Comment: El MTP realemente no es fallo de tu aplicación por eso lo comento. Prueba a instarlar una aplicacon cuqluiera y desinstalarla a ver si sigue dando ese error. Te dejo un enlace a wikipedia sobre el MTP que lo explica mejor que yo, pero bassicamente lo usa android para transferencia de datos: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTP